# Apache Startup doesn't work with PHP 5.3 in Debian Lenny

Tags: apache-http-server, php, php5

Today I updated PHP 5.2 to 5.3 but then Apache Startup doesn't work.

Apache says:

> Starting web server: apache2apache2: Syntax error on line 205 of
>   /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server:
>   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory
>
> Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

Is downgrading PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.2 a good idea? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

See if the libphp5.so module is installed elsewhere on the server using the find and locate command

```
# find / -name libphp5.so
# locate libphp5.so
```

if it is, copy it to /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ directory and restart Apache.
If the file is not present, install the ‘libapache2-mod-php5′ package, the PHP5 module for Apache2. It adds the required FilesMatch directives to the Apache configuration.

```
# apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

The ‘libapache2-mod-php5′ package will create the libphp5.so file under the modules directory and apache2 will restart successfully

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

---

if you want to go with downgrade:

Remove PHP

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-common
sudo apt-get remove php5-cli
sudo apt-get remove php5
sudo apt-get autoremove memcached
```

Update your sources list to point to PHP 5.2

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove the references to PHP 5.3 packages. For me that was:

```
deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
```

Add the following 5.2 packages:

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable all
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org/ stable all
```

Install PHP 5.2

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Reinstall any PHP modules your application requires. For me that was:

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo reboot
```